# Libreoffice don't open files outside Document folder

Tags: 18.04, gnome, permissions, libreoffice

After Ubuntu upgrade, Libreoffice stops to open files outside home Document folder.

Ubuntu 18.04.5
Libreoffice installed via snap

```
libreoffice --version
LibreOffice 7.2.0.4 ce769e3009755dcf0082844e386f5dca4c8ecb2f
```

Trying to call it from console (to see if there is any error messagem):

```
cd ~
echo "I have full access to the folder" > file.txt
libreoffice.calc file.ods
```

It halts with a Dialog saying [image: Error dialog]

Translated to English: "It was not possible to create a lock file to exclusive access by LibreOffice, by missing permissions to create a lock file on the choosen place"

I've tried to uninstall Libreoffice twice and did multiple attempts via ppa and also from official repository. Same error :(

Libreoffice 6 works fine. The problem just occurs with 7.1 version and above.

I've also tried this solution: askubuntu.com/questions/643382/libre-office-wont-open but the problem persists. In fact, a new config file was not created after I deleted it.

How can I debug to find the permission problem ?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1363797/edit) and add the information in the above comment in your question. The comments are mainly for us to ask for clarifications and point out issues like this. You should update your question.

Comment: Does the problem persist when you open the application directly, instead of from a file?  Also, where are these files located, exactly?

Comment: Where in the filesystem are you trying to save a file? You lack permission to write to many locations outside your /home/$YOU fir.

Comment: Maybe it's because LibreOffice is installed as snap package. Snap applications can have limited access to filesystem. Try uninstalling snap version of LibreOffice and install regular .deb package version.

Comment: Yes. Same problem occurs using GUI. I have full permission to the folder where I'm trying to access.

Comment: I've tried already using apt install and via PPA install.

Comment: Do you have full permissions to the parent folder that you are trying to access?  Subfolders and files inherit the parent folder permissions.

Comment: Yes Terrance. I have full access.

Comment: Can you please paste that info into your question?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue today.  I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  I had upgraded from 6.4.7.2 to 7.2.7.  This caused two issues.  I could not open any file not in my $Home directory and documents I opened in my $Home directory gave me errors.  When I tried to save them anywhere other than in Documents it would fail.  The files both in $Home and outside of $home were files I had been editing with libre office before the upgrade, and worked after my fix so I can verify I had permissions to them.  I tried upgrading to 7.3.5 and that did not fix the issue.

This seems to be related to:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1751005

I tried sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.libreoffice.program.* and it didn't work because it gave me an error I did not try to debug.
I also tried updating the alias file but that did not work for me.

In the end I downgraded to 6.4.7.2 and everything is working again.
https://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/6.4.7.2/deb/x86_64/

This is kind of old so hoping this helps anyone new that might come across this in searches.